# How to schedule a Hangout on AIR (HOA) programmatically in android?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-hangouts

I want to integrate **Hangout On Air** in my android app.

Is there any documentation to integrate Hangout On Air in android app?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/

And particularly this:
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair